# argparse "compulsory" optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Python's `argparse` module has what are called 'optional' arguments. All arguments whose name starts with `-` or `--` are optional by default. Typically, compulsory arguments are positional, and hence when running the program, they are not explicitly *named*.

For example, in a script which had:

```
parser.add_argument('language', help="Output language")
```

Invocations would look like:

```
$ hello-world czech
```

It may sometimes be nicer to have a compulsory argument passed by name (e.g. scripted invocations are easier to read this way), but still be compulsory. i.e.

```
$ hello-world --use-lang czech
```

How to achieve this? Named arguments are called 'optional' in the `argparse` documentation, which makes it sound like they *cannot* be compulsory. Is there a way to make them compulsory?

Comment: and then how to make the `--help` look right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180527/argparse-required-arguments-listed-under-optional-arguments

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to canonical documentation, it is possible to [declare 'optional' arguments that are compulsory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required). You use the `required` named argument of `add_argument`:

```
parser.add_argument('--use-lang', required=True, help="Output language")
```

Comment: Often times, you can easily make a "required" option optional again by assigning a suitable default value to the option.

Comment: @user2864740 - I just wanted to document this because I had to spend some time reading the official docs before figuring it out. I don't blog, and anyway, SO is a much better forum than a private blog. I often search SO before asking google.

Comment: The documentation *already* documents this; reading documentation/API is a developer's responsibility. Again, I'm not against self-answering, but *give the community time*. (Or go start a blog, which is a great way to write/vent/re-document these sort of things!)

Comment: @user2864740 - I was just following [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/179533). The answer is now a community wiki. Unfortunately, seems I cannot turn the question into one now. If you think this isn't a great question because it is already documented, you might want to downvote the question. I have no problem deleting substandard questions.

Comment: There is some debate among Python developers about the name 'optional arguments' and whether it can be improved.  http://bugs.python.org/issue9694.  There is a long history in the UNIX world of calling arguments with `-,--` flags `options` or `optionals`.